# Linux application codebase

Tags: linux

What is the Linux command to find out whether a Linux third party application is 32 bit or 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

you can use file:

```
user@host:~$ file /bin/ls 
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

In my case a 64-bit LSB executable..

Answer (score 2):

`file(1)`

```
$ file =ls
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

Comment: The equal sign used this way is a zsh-ism, in case anyone wonders. See `man zshexpn` under "Filename expansion" ('=' expansion) for details.